# Using Laudenbach-Poénaru to justify Kirby diagrams

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

It is always referred as the "classical argument" that one only needs to specify the 1 and 2-handles in the Kirby diagram of a 4-manifold $X$ since by Laudenbach-Poénaru there is a unique way to attach 3 and 4-handles to get a closed 4-manifold, as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288246/are-there-kirby-diagrams-with-3-handles) as well. The theorem by Laudenbach-Poénaru says

> Every diffeomorphism of $\sharp^k (S^1\times S^2)$ extends to $\natural^k (S^1\times D^3)$.

I have two questions about this:

1. Fix a closed 4-manifold $X$ and let $X_2$ denote the union of 1 and 2-handles in its handle decomposition. By considering a lower dimensional analogue of it, I think I was able to understand how attaching a 3-handle "cancels" an $S^1\times S^2$. But conversely, why is it the case that if $X$ is closed then $\partial X_2$ must be $\sharp^k (S^1\times S^2)$?
2. How exactly are we using Laudenbach-Poénaru to justify that specifying 1 and 2-handles in the Kirby diagram is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see why (1) is true. Since $-f$ is a Morse function such that a $k$-handle of $f$ corresponds to a $(4-k)$-handle of $-f$, the union of 3 and 4-handles should be $\natural^k(S^1\times D^3)$. Now, assuming that $X$ is closed,
$$\partial X_2 = \partial\big(\natural^k(S^1\times D^3)\big) = \sharp^k(S^1\times S^2)$$
Armed with this fact, we can now answer (2). Once we specify the 1 and 2-handles in the Kirby diagram, we actually also specify a smooth structure on $X_2$ because there is a predetermined way to smooth out the regions where handles are attached. Hence, restricting this smooth structure to the boundary, we have a canonical smooth structure on $\partial X_2$. Now, no matter how we attach the 3 and 4-handles, the corresponding diffeomorphism on $\partial X_2$ will extend to $X$ by Laudenbach-Poénaru.

Does this seem correct? I'd appreciate if someone can check my reasoning!